# Can an outlook plugin control element support multiple action elements?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to combine 2 custom vendor add-ins in outlook to support our transition from 1 product to another. Since the web apps behind the plugins are built and supported by the vendor, I have no access to change/update the code.

Is it possible to have 2 action elements within the same control element so that when I click the add in button, it triggers both a "ShowTaskpane" and an "ExecuteFunction" action?

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible to have 2 action elements within the same control element. If you would like to request this as a feature we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Github Label: “Type: product feature request”

https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions

As a workaround, could you not just perform whatever actions you would do in ExecuteFunction in your ShowTaskpane code during onReady/initialize? (Perhaps I am not understanding the scenario completely)

Comment: unfortunately I can't run the executefunction code in the showtaskpane code because the showtaskpane code calls a web app that's hosted and managed by the vendor so we have no access to the code.